# Create a US map that combines geographic spatial dimensions and a data dimension

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, rgl

I'm creating a map of the United States that highlights some specific states defined by a categorical variable.  What I'd like to do is introduce a data dimension to these states as well.  Something akin to a geographic histogram like in [the image below](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc02/pap0239/p02392.gif);

[image]

So far I've just gotten to the two dimensional level using ggplot.  I've read about mapping in RGL's 3D environment but I'm not sure how to implement it.

```
ggplot(data = map.data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
    geom_polygon(aes(fill = expansion, alpha = fpl.cat)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('#004487', '#91AF5F', '#F09628'), guide=FALSE) +
    scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(.4, 1), guide=FALSE) +
    geom_path(colour = 'black', linestyle = 3) +
    coord_map()
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a 3D plot? A quick Google search shows you can accomplish the same thing with four colors. E.g., http://www.geo.unizh.ch/~annal/Choropleth%20maps.html

Comment: A `dput()` of `map.data` would help us show you possible alternatives.

Comment: Or just a stick with a scatterplot. The 3D-ness obscures completely Nevada, Kansas, Vermont and New Hampshire (at least), and it's near impossible to compare the heights of, say Oklahoma and California, or Texas and New York.